# Convert string em formato binário para PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, binary

Gostaria de saber como gero um arquivo PDF através de uma *string* com valores binários, os valores na verdade devem virar um texto (de acordo com a tabela ASCII) e serem gravados em PDF.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma mas não obtive sucesso:

```
string teste = "010001010101111001111111";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(teste);

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:/teste.pdf", bytes);
```

O que está errado no código? O PDF até é criado mas nada é escrito nele, o mesmo nem chega a abrir.

Answer (score 1):

Resgate os bytes da `String` binária:

```
public Byte[] GetBytesFromBinaryString(String binary)
{
  var list = new List<Byte>();

  for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
  {
    String t = binary.Substring(i, 8);

    list.Add(Convert.ToByte(t, 2));
  }

  return list.ToArray();
}


byte[] bytes = GetBytesFromBinaryString("010001010101111001111111");
```

Por fim escreva o PDF:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:/teste.pdf", bytes);
```

---

Resposta baseada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion).

Comment: Olá, Fiz dessa forma que você sugeriu porém o PDF não abre, o Adobe Reader diz que não há suporte a este tipo de arquivo ou ele foi danificado. O que pode ser?

Comment: Insira esse trecho: `var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);` e poste aqui o valor de `text`, por favor.

Comment: O valor retornado foi "E^ "

Comment: Era isso o que estava escrito em binário?

Comment: Sim, na verdade foi aleatório o numero gerado. Mas fiz um teste com o meu nome "Raphael" em binário, e também não gerou o pdf com o conteúdo.

Comment: Em modo debug, quando passo o mouse em cima da classe "File", aparecem 3 propriedades: ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87
GetFileExInfoStandard = 0

Será que isso tem algo a ver?

Comment: FIz um teste salvando como TXT e foi normal, o problema é gerar PDF

Comment: Entendi. Já pensou em usar algum framework para gerar o PDF? Dê uma olhada no [iText](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Uma das novas funcionalidades do C# 7.0 são as *binary literals*. Com ele, a solução para esse caso ficaria mais simples:

```
var bytes = 0b0100_0101_0101_1110_0111_1111;

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:/teste.pdf", bytes);
```

Referência: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/